# How to set an initial size for an STL container of reference_wrapper?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, reference-wrapper

I have a `vector` of some reference type wrapped in `reference_wrapper`. Since I need to fill this container out of order I'm trying to set an initial size for the container:

```
vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>> v(5);

v[3] = ..
v[2] = ..
v[4] = ..
v[5] = ..
v[1] = ..
```

This fails to compile with an error like:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::reference_wrapper<int>::reference_wrapper()’
```

Is there a workaround to make this work or do I have to use a `vector<T*>` for this purpose?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)? It does not provide a default constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could provide a prototype, sort of your own "uninitialised" value:

```
T blank;
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>> v(5, ref(blank));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use std::vector::reserve method.

```
std::vector< std::reference_wrapper<T> > v;
v.reserve(5);
v.push_back( std::ref( t0 ) ); 
v.push_back( std::ref( t1 ) ); // and etc.. where  t0, t1 - some variable type of T.
```

[Coliru example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/873629394d0ae5c2)

Comment: `reverse` doesn't actually increase the size of the vector but only the internal storage of it. As I said I need to push the elements out of order so `push_back` is not an option for me.

Comment: Leads to the question of what do you expect the values of v[0] - v[4] if you've only populated v[5]?  A reference_wrapper has to refer to _something_.